# how to calculate the phase angle

Tags: trigonometry

When we transform $a\sin x+b\cos x=c$ into $a\sin x+b\cos x=R\sin(x+k)$, we calculate the $k$ angle by $k=\tan(b/a)$. By using calculator, we get a positive or negative degree value for $k$. I know that when we invert $\tan$, we get many solutions, due to the periodic nature of the tan function, which are given by $180n+m$ (where n is an integer) and $m$ is the value of $k$ that the calculator gave us. Then, we somehow determine which of the $180n+m$ we take for $k$ (based on the signs of $a$ and $b$). My question is why we do this? I assume that since we are talking about a function with period, the $R\sin(x+k)$, and the $k$ is a shift of the $\sin x$ function across the x line, we need to specify which $k$ of the $180n+m$ we take.

Can you elaborate please? Thanks

Comment: See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atan2#Definition_and_computation

Comment: thanks that seems to explain something, but can you elaborate? I mean it only mentions when x>0, but not when x>0 and y>0 or when x>0 and y<0! also, how do we ended up with that table?

Comment: I also need to know the logic behind why we cannot calculate the phase angle by 180n+m and we have to utilize atan2

Comment: Think of $-\sin\theta-\cos\theta=c$ and $\sin\theta+\cos\theta=c$ Should the two $k$s be same?

Comment: probably not! but, we only learn in school the atan, not the atan2 ! now it is the first time I encounter a problem where the atan2 is needed! why that? why we even use atan, as it's not 100% right? shouldn't we use atan2 all the time?

Comment: atan2 is used for programming. By using atan2, the program will determine the correct quadrant so you don't have to write more code to make sure the atan is returning the correct angle.

Answer (score 2):

Let's take an arbitrary equation
$$
A\sin(x) + B\cos(x) = R\sin(x + \phi) \quad (1)
$$
We can write $\sin(x + \phi)$ as
$$
\sin(x + \phi) = \sin(x)\cos(\phi) + \sin(\phi)\cos(x)\qquad (2)
$$
Therefore, $R\sin(x + \phi) = R\sin(x)\cos(\phi) + R\sin(\phi)\cos(x)$. Let's equate equations (1) and (2).
$$
A\sin(x) + B\cos(x) = R\sin(x)\cos(\phi) + R\sin(\phi)\cos(x)
$$
So $A = R\cos(\phi)$ and $B = R\sin(\phi)$.  Then $A^2 + B^2 = R^2(\cos^2(\phi) + \sin^2(\phi)) = R^2$; that is, $R = \sqrt{A^2+B^2}$.  Then
$$
\tan(\phi) = \frac{B\sin(\phi)}{A\cos(\phi)} =\frac{B}{A}\\
\phi = \tan^{-1}\Big(\frac{B}{A}\Big)
$$
where if $A,B > 0$ we are in quadrant 1, $A>0$ and $B<0$ we are in quad 4, $A<0$ and $B>0$ we are in quad 2, and quad 3 for $A,B<0$.

We can then do this for $R\cos(x-\phi)$ as well where 
$$
R\cos(x-\phi) = R\cos(x)\cos(\phi) + R\sin(x)\sin(\phi)
$$
Why dont you give it a try.

Comment: when we are in 4th quadrant, is it the minus angle or the 360 minus the acute angle?

Comment: When you are in the 4th quadrant the angle range is $270 < \phi < 360$ degrees or $3\pi/2 < \phi <2\pi$ rad. For example, $\tan^{-1}(-2/1) = -1.107$ rad.  If we add 2pi, we have $5.176$ rad which is in quadrant 4.

Comment: so there is no possibility that the phase angle is negative?

Comment: -1.107 is the same as 5.176.  You can call it what ever you want but most people use angle arguments between 0 and 2pi or 0 and 360.  However, in complex analysis the principle argument can also be defined between  $-\pi$ and pi.

Comment: so you mean that if we find ϕ to be negative, then we will end in the exact same result, if we do Rsin(x-ϕ) and Rsin(x+360-ϕ)?

Comment: @trig Consider we obtain the phase angle to be $-\pi$.  Then $\sin(x-\pi) = -\sin(x)$ or if we added $2\pi - \pi = \pi$, then $\sin(x+\pi) = -\sin(x)$

Comment: so it's the same. but the problem is that we don't get the same for the equation −sinθ−cosθ=c !